# Web component developed using stencil not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, web-component, polyfills, stenciljs

I have some stencil components developed, but after production build the dist js included in plain HTML and using the component as

```
<my-comp></my-comp>
```

is not working there, getting error as calling delete on 'included' is not allowed in strict mode.

[image]

below is my **stencil config**

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core'
import { sass } from '@stencil/sass'
export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'mep-components',
  srcDir: 'src',
  buildEs5: true,
  extras: {
    cssVarsShim: true,
    dynamicImportShim: true,
    shadowDomShim: true,
    safari10: true,
    scriptDataOpts: true,
    appendChildSlotFix: false,
    cloneNodeFix: false,
    slotChildNodesFix: true,
  },
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist'
    },
    {
      type: 'www'
    }
  ],
  devServer: {
    reloadStrategy: 'pageReload',
    port: 4444
  },
  plugins: [sass()]
}
```

below is the package JSON
**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "web-components",
  "module": "./dist/index.js",
  "collection": "./dist/collection/collection-manifest.json",
  "types": "./dist/types/components.d.ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/index.cjs.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "stencil build --dev --watch --serve",
    "build": "stencil build --prod && node ./src/tasks/after.build.js",
    "server": "json-server --watch db.json",
    "task": "node ./src/tasks/someTask.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@stencil/core": "^2.6.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "stencil-click-outside": "^1.7.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@stencil/sass": "^1.4.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.6",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "workbox-build": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, IE11 is dead and buried, its vendor has abandonded it for years ago.

Comment: Is there anything can be done with polyfilling

Comment: Use Google, there were plenty of polyfills used in the past. My best advice: refuse to work on IE projects. You will have to pay the price twice, once for having to use outdated tech, and double because you are not learning the modern stuff.

Comment: Have you used [the `extras` config](https://stenciljs.com/docs/config-extras) to support legacy browsers? By default, Stencil does not work on IE11, but with polyfills it can support IE11. By using the `extras` config, the legacy browsers can download and run polyfills.

Comment: @YuZhou I have used the extra config updated the same in the question have a look.

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? So that we can have a test and see how to help. With only the **config** and **package.json**, we can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @YuZhou here is the [code repo](https://github.com/rahulgupta-dev/web-components)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code repo. I download the code repo and run `npm install` and serve the production build, it doesn't show the error in your question. It shows another error [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLhhu.png).

Comment: @YuZhou, run npm run build and use the \dist\mep-components\mep-component.js to some plain HTML use below tag in you HTML.

**<mep-listing list-id="INTERNAL_USER_LISTING" page-size="50">
</mep-listing>**

then you will get the error.

Comment: Still can't reproduce the issue. I test [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E9Bi.png) according to what you said. The result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evn3w.png). It will waste a lot of time to support IE11. I suggest you drop the IE11 support and just support your app in modern browsers, as Microsoft has announced that IE11 will retire on June 15, 2022.

Answer (score 0):

One of the breaking changes in Stencil 2.0 was that support for Internet Explorer 11 is disabled by default, it's now opt-in. You need to manually enable it.

> https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/main/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#opt-in-for-ie11-edge-16-18-and-safari-10-builds